# How can I save workspace as... in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have a workspace and a spring mvc 3.x web app as my project.

```
/code2
/code1
+ /workspace1
  + /project1
```

I want to save my workspace into another directory and reference that same project directory and delete that old workspace directory.

So...

```
   /code2  <-- New area for workspace
    + /workspace2 <-- The copied save as...worksace from worksace1
```

However, I want to delete the old workspace workspace one and reference that same project in the project directory.

```
   /code2  
    + /workspace2  <-- this should reference the project in project1
   /code1
    + /project1
```

How can I accomplish this?  I don't see a save as with eclipse and I would like to keep all my config/editor settings from my workspace instead of creating a new one to re-reference the project1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but requires a few steps. First, move the whole workspace to code2. Then move the project from the workspace to code1.
After that, open Eclipse with the moved workspace and reimport the project.

Comment: awesome!  worked great!  QQ: I want to check in my workspace settings (server tomcat stuff/ports, and whatever else I need to recreate my workspace settings but there are a ton of temp files....so not sure what I should really be checking into svn.  I don't want to check in thousands of temp files. Any advice?